# Calling function from a class in project 1 from project 2

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, multi-project

I have a c# solution. For the solution i have 2 projects setup. One is a web application and one is a class library.  I created a class in the class library that has a static method that i want to call from the web application project. I added a reference to project 1 from project 2. I added the using Project1 namespace to a file in project 2 and in the file im trying to call `MyClass.MyFunction("test");` but for some reason visual studio is forcing me to put the namespace in front of MyClass for it to work.

example:

```
Project1.MyClass.MyFunction("test");
```

does anyone know why its making me use the namespace even though I have it declared in a using statement?

Comment: Are you calling it from a .cs file or an .aspx file?

Comment: Can you post some code? I.e. MyClass and the calling class along with namespaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this using one of these at the top of your web .cs file:

```
using MyClass=Project1.MyClass;  // A

using Project1.MyClass;  // B
```

If option A works, but option B doesn't, then you probably have a MyClass defined in the Project2 namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have more than one class called 'MyClass' - one in each project, so its forcing you to choose which one you want.